# getDownloadUrl is not working it says cannot find symbol method getDownloadUrl

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I set an onclicklistner in my update button, where i want to upload image and username in firebasestore(firestore version 22.1.2). I have add all firestore depandency in gradle, getDownloadUrl is not working it says cannot find symbol method getDownloadUrl

```
String user_id = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

StorageReference image_path = storageReference.child("profile_image").child(user_id+".jpg");

image_path.putFile(mainImageURI).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

        if(task.isSuccessful()){
            Uri download_uri = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl(); //Have error in this getDownloadUrl().

            Map<String,String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
            userMap.put("name",user_name);
            userMap.put("image",download_uri);
            firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).set(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        finish();
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this,"The User Settings are updated ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(mainIntent);


                    }else {
                        String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this,"Firestore Error: "+error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                    setupProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });



        }else{
            String error = task.getException().getMessage();
            Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this,"Image Error: "+error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            setupProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }


    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
        public async Task getLinkAsync(string path)
        {
            FirebaseStorage storage = new FirebaseStorage("******-****.appspot.com");
            var starsRef = storage.Child(path);
            string link = await starsRef.GetDownloadUrlAsync();
        }
```